# Complex eigenvalues in linear systems of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $X'=AX \tag1$, with
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & \beta \\
-\beta & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and $\beta \neq 0$. The eigenvalues are $\pm i\beta$ and their corresponding eigenvectors are $\left ( \begin{matrix}1 \\ i\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left ( \begin{matrix}1 \\ -i\end{matrix}\right)$.

Here, "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos" by Hirsch, Smale and Devaney only says to use the first pair of eigenvalue and eigenvector to find the general solution of system $(1)$, which is $$
X(t)=e^{i\beta t}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 \\ i
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$ It doesn't say anything about the remaining pair of eigenvalue and eigenvector. Why is that?

Comment: This is a little weird. Of course $\exp(-i\beta t)(1, -i)^\top$ is another solution. All linear combinations of those solutions are solutions, too. In fact every solution is a linear combination of these two.

Comment: I have the book and it is nowhere said that. It is said that the $X(t)$ is *a* solution to the equation $X'=AX$, not the general one. In fact, they obtain the general one by decomposing $X(t)$ into the sum of a real and a pure imaginary part, and then noticing that both those parts satisfy the differential equation. They then conclude that the general real solution is a linear combination of the real and the imaginary parts of $X(t)$. The same result is obtained by considering the other pair of eigenvalue/eigenvector and doing the necessary algebra.

Comment: You don't need the second eigenpair, since the first form a fundamental set of solutions as you may verify by expanding out into trigonometric form.

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the general case,

Consider $X'=AX$, with
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta \\
-\beta & \alpha
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

The the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\overline{\lambda_2}$, where $\alpha=\Re(\lambda)$ and $\beta=\Im(\lambda)$. It is clear that the eigenvector is

$$V=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\i \end{matrix}\right)$$

This implies that the complex solution is given by $X_c(t)=\exp(\lambda t)V=\exp((\alpha+i\beta)t)V$.

Recall the Euler's equation,

$$\exp(i\beta t)=\cos(\beta t)+i\sin(\beta t)$$

This yields,

\begin{align}
X_c(t)=\exp(\lambda t)V&=\exp(\alpha t)(\cos(\beta t)+i\sin(\beta t))\left(\begin{matrix}1\\i \end{matrix}\right)\\
&=\exp(\alpha t)\left(\begin{matrix}\cos(\beta t)+i\sin(\beta t)\\i\cos(\beta t)-\sin(\beta t)\end{matrix}\right)\\
&=\exp(\alpha t)\left(\begin{matrix}\cos(\beta t)\\-\sin(\beta t)\end{matrix}\right)+i\exp(\alpha t)\left(\begin{matrix}\sin(\beta t)\\\cos(\beta t)\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

By basic algebra you can check that indeed the $\Im(X_c(t))$ and $\Re(X_c(t))$ are real solution and independent. Which implies that the general real solution is given by

\begin{align}
X(t)&=a\Re(X_c(t))+b\Im(X_c(t))\\
&=\exp(\alpha t)\left[a\left(\cos(\beta t)\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)-\sin(\beta t)\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)\right)+b\left(\sin(\beta t)\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)-\cos(\beta t)\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)\right)\right]\\
&=\exp(\alpha t)\left(\begin{matrix}\cos(\beta t) & \sin(\beta t)\\
-\sin(\beta t) & \cos(\beta t)\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Note that the middle matrix is the rotation matrix.

In your case, with $\alpha=0$ implies that the phase portrait is a center.